# Hacer que un boton desactive todos los demas botones dentro de un cliclo for

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hola estoy aprendiendo JavaScript y quería ayuda para hacer la siguiente funcionalidad... Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que al presionar el btn1 de la fila 0 se deshabiliten todos los demas botones de las demas filas (el btn2 de la fila cero, btn1 y btn2 de la fila 1, etc etc). en este ejemplo que hice para poder orientarme es fijo la cantidad de filas sin embargo la idea es que se pueda aplicar en una tabla donde la cantidad de filas no va a ser fija...
Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias de antemano

***codigo de php***

```
<?php for ($i=0; $i <3; $i++) { ?>
  <label>fila <?php echo $i; ?></label>
    <button id="btn1<?php echo $i ?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" onclick="deshabilitar(<?php echo $i ?>)" value="<?php echo $i; ?>">btn1</button>
    <button id="btn2<?php echo $i ?>" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">btn2</button>
    <br>
  <?php }  ?>
```

***Codigo de Javascript***

```
var btn1=document.getElementById('btn1'),
btn2=document.getElementById('btn2'),
contador=0;


function deshabilitar(num) {

    if (contador==0) {

        document.getElementById('btn2'+num).disabled=true;
        
        contador=1;
    }else{
        document.getElementById('btn2'+num).disabled=false;
        contador=0;
    }
}
```

[image: imagen de la vista]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es, al darle click en un botón, deshabilitar todos los botones y luego habilitar apenas el que has clicado: Algo como:

```js
const onClickButton = (button, buttons) => {
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.toggleAttribute('disabled');
  });
  
  button.removeAttribute('disabled');
};

const registerButtonClickEventListeners = () => {
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-container .btn');
  
  buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      onClickButton(event.target, buttons);
    });
  });
};

registerButtonClickEventListeners();
```

```css
.btn-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.btn-container .btn {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-container">
  <button class="btn">btn1</button>
  <button class="btn">btn2</button>
  <button class="btn">btn3</button>
  <button class="btn">btn4</button>
  <button class="btn">btn5</button>
  <button class="btn">btn6</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow muchas gracias en verdad, solo tengo una duda para hacer que se habiliten con el  mismo boton que queda activo bastaria con modificar esta linea "button.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');" con button.setAttribute('enabled', 'enabled'); el chiste es que al presionar el boton pueda desactivar y activar todos los botones muchas gracias de todas formas

Comment: Hola @EMMAHUERTA. No, porque "enabled" no es un atributo valido. Hay que añadir o remover el atributo "disabled". Lo puedes hacer com `setAttribute`/`removeAttribute` o aun mejor, con `toggleAttribute`. He editado la respuesta para que funcione como deseas.

Comment: Oh ya ya ya muchas muchas muchas gracias ya pude hacer que funcione en un ciclo foreach  me acabas de hacer la semana en verdad muchas gracias